# jQuery - How to get dynamically created submit input clicks

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click, submit

I have struggled so long with this problem, so that i have to ask your help. In my current project i have to make dynamically new submit buttons, but problem is that i cant get button presses. Here is demo what i made.

**HTML**

```
<button id="AddButton">Add Input</button>
<br />
<br />
<div>
   <input type="submit" name="Button[]" id="Button-0" value="Button 0"> <br />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var i = 0;

$('#AddButton').click(function() {
  ++i;
  var newInput = '<input type="submit" name="Button[]" id="Button-'+i+'" value="Button '+i+'"> <br />';
  $('div').append(newInput);
});


$('input').click(function() {
  var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(inputID); 
});
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/71/

I made easy debug. Every input press makes alert, and as you can see, jquery made submits doesn't make any alerts.

Comment: Asked billion times a year...

Comment: still so many wrong answers :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `on` jQuery function.

Also, add a class for appended buttons.

```
$(document).on("click", ".myFavoriteClass", function() {
   var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(inputID); 
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/75/)

In the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) we find this:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

So we will detect clicks on `document` with these parameters:

- `events`: "click"
- `selector`: ".myFavoriteClass"

### Direct and delegated events

When a selector **is provided**, the event handler **is referred to as delegated**. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to** `.on()`. To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page.

If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

[read more on the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)]

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function() {
    var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(inputID); 
});
```

You need to use `on` for dynamic generated elements in order to bind an event on them.

[See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/72/)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('div').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var inputID = this.id;
    alert(inputID); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any input within the `div` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/79/)

Answer (score 2):

You need event delegation for dynamically generated element's

```
$(document).on('click','input:submit',function() {
   var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(inputID); 
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/76/

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

Put this:

```
$('input').click(function() {
   var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(inputID); 
});
```

Inside the `$('#AddButton').click(function()` function, at the end. Like this:

```
var i = 0;

$('#AddButton').click(function() {
  ++i;
  var newInput = '<input type="submit" name="Button[]" id="Button-'+i+'" value="Button '+i+'"> <br />';
  $('div').append(newInput);

  $("input").click(function() {
    var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(inputID);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on`:

```
 $("#Button-" + i).on("click", function() {
   var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(inputID); 
});
```

This will attach a new `click` event handler for your button.

http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/78/

You may want to use one function which you can attach `$(input).click` to as well as `$("#Button-" + i)`

You can also use `bind` however `on` is the preffered method as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: But `.on("click", function() {...})` does the same thing as `.click(function() {...})`. And `.bind("click"...` does the same as `.click(...`

Answer (score 0):

First assign a class to all the buttons that you are creating instead of assigning them the same id. Second, use jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind the click event to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**worked fine for me**

**Simply add class to the input field like this**

```
<input type="text" class="actionClass" id="my_id1"/>
<input type="text" class="actionClass" id="my_id2"/>
```

**and then jquery code should be like this**

```
$('.actionClass').bind('click',function(event){
    console.log('clicked: id ='+this.id);
});
```